# is there any way to make possible the post request in my django and react project?

Tags: reactjs, django

the frontend code is

```
`import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import Select from "react-select";

function AddDetails() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    first_name: '',
    last_name: '',
    mobile_number: '',
    services: [],
    years_of_experience: '',
    license_certificate: null,
    min_charge: '',
    charge_after_one_hour: '',
    street_name: '',
    house_number: '',
    ward: '',
    panchayath_municipality_corporation: '',
    taluk: '',
    district: '',
    state: '',
    country: '',
  });

  const [services, setServices] = useState([]);
  const [selectedServices, setSelectedServices] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch the list of services from the Django backend
    axios
      .get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/services/')
      .then((response) => {
        setServices(response.data.results);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }, []);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    if (name === 'services') {
      const selectedServices = Array.from(e.target.selectedOptions, (option) =>
        option.value
      );
      console.log('Selected Services:', selectedServices); 

      setFormData({
        ...formData,
        services: selectedServices,
      });
    } else {
      setFormData({
        ...formData,
        [name]: value,
      });
    }
  };

  const serviceOptions = services.map((service) => ({
    value: service.id,
    label: service.Title,
  }));

  const handleSelectChange = (selectedOptions) => {
    setSelectedServices(selectedOptions);
    const selectedServiceIds = selectedOptions.map((option) => option.value);
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      services: selectedServiceIds,
    });
  };

  
  const handleFileChange = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];

    if (file) {
      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = (e) => {
        const fileContent = e.target.result;
        setFormData({
          ...formData,
          license_certificate: fileContent,
        });
        dataToSend.append('license_certificate', file);
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  };

  const user=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))
  const userId=user.id
  console.log(userId)


  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    const dataToSend = new FormData();
    dataToSend.append('first_name', formData.first_name);
    dataToSend.append('last_name', formData.last_name);
    dataToSend.append('mobile_number', formData.mobile_number);
    dataToSend.append('years_of_experience', formData.years_of_experience);
    dataToSend.append('min_charge', formData.min_charge);
    dataToSend.append('charge_after_one_hour', formData.charge_after_one_hour);
    dataToSend.append('street_name', formData.street_name);
    dataToSend.append('house_number', formData.house_number);
    dataToSend.append('ward', formData.ward);
    dataToSend.append('panchayath_municipality_corporation',    formData.panchayath_municipality_corporation);
    dataToSend.append('taluk', formData.taluk);
    dataToSend.append('district', formData.district);
    dataToSend.append('state', formData.state);
    dataToSend.append('country', formData.country);
    formData.services.forEach((serviceId) => {
      dataToSend.append('services', serviceId);
    });
    dataToSend.append('userId', userId);
  
    // Handle the file
    if (formData.license_certificate) {
      dataToSend.append('license_certificate', formData.license_certificate);
    }
  
    try {
      const response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/add_details/', dataToSend, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
      });

      console.log('User details added successfully');
      toast.success('Submitted successfully');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Failed to add user details', error);
    }
  };`
```

backend view i used is given here

```
``class UserDetailsCreate(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserDetailsSerializer
    
    def perform_create(self, serializer,request):
        user_id = self.request.data.get('userId')
        user = get_object_or_404(User, id=user_id)
        serializer.save(user=user)`
```

i am trying to post user details `additionally(signup)` from profile page but i cant post it shows the

```
error bad request : "Bad Request: /add_details/
```

> [01/Nov/2023 16:26:07] "POST /add_details/ HTTP/1.1" 400 760" , so
> please go through my code and give me the corrected code`

Comment: Asking people to give you the corrected code will not work here. There is an issue in the validation of your `UserDetailsCreate`. You need to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Post Api form data will be in request.POST, so try

```
user_id = self.request.POST.get('userId')
```